# Definir titulo com echo em PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou tendo um problema com a CMS que estou criando.

Quero definir o titulo do site utilizando a função echo do php, assim:

```
<?php
$ever = json_decode('../json/data.json');

$everthing = json_decode('../json/info.json');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>


 <title><?php echo 'Rodrigo' ?></title>
<body>

</body>

</head>
```

Mas não estou conseguindo.

Edit: Obrigado por todas as respostas, essa comunidade é realmente fantástica. Mas era um problema com o meu servidor web, mudei e rodou tudo.

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro ?

Comment: Não, no titulo da página aparece o seguinte: <?php echo 'Rodrigo' ?>

Comment: seu arquivp é .php? Pois o código está sendo exibido ao invés de compilado

Comment: Por que `<title><?php echo 'Rodrigo' ?></title>` e não `<title>Rodrigo</title>`? Se não irá usar variável, não entendi o motivo.

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro você precisa entender...

**Qual é a diferença entre uma página da Web PHP e HTML?**

Os arquivos PHP são semelhantes aos arquivos HTML, mas podem incluir código HTML e PHP. O código PHP é analisado (ou executado) pelo servidor da Web quando a página é acessada e a saída resultante é gravada como HTML na página da Web. Quando um usuário acessa uma página PHP, seu navegador da Web só recebe o código HTML, já que o servidor Web processou o código PHP em segundo plano. A maioria das páginas do PHP é processada tão rapidamente que não diminui notavelmente o carregamento da página da Web.

A extensão .php é importante, pois informa ao servidor da Web que a página pode incluir código PHP. Portanto, ele deve ser executado através do mecanismo PHP do servidor antes de ser enviado para o navegador da Web de um cliente. Isso permite que o conteúdo dinâmico seja gerado toda vez que a página da Web for carregada, com base nas variáveis ​​incluídas no código PHP. Por exemplo, as páginas PHP podem carregar objetos, como a data e a hora atuais, dados de campos de formulário enviados por um usuário ou informações de um banco de dados. Ainda assim, quando a página chega ao navegador da Web do usuário, tudo é formatado como HTML.

Sabendo disso você deve perceber que sua extensão está como .html e não .php, logo, a primeira coisa a se fazer é alterar isso. Depois você precisa entender a estrutura básica do HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Titulo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Cabeçalho</h1>
        <p>Parágrafo</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ou seja, outro erro está na sua organização estrutural do HTML.
E por último e não menos importante, o ; ao final do echo que todo comando php deve contar ao ser finalizado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            <?php echo 'Rodrigo'; ?>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

O código precisa ser **.php** , provavelmente está **.html**

e usa-se ponto e vírgula ao final do comando como boa prática, assim:

```
<title><?php echo 'Rodrigo'; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu código tem uma parte não aconselhável se você quiser adicionar mais código depois disto

Originalmente você tem:

```
<title><?php echo 'Rodrigo' ?></title>
```

Mas no PHP, no fim de cada ordem / comando é necessário adicionar um `;`. Assim, o código fica.

```
<title><?php echo 'Rodrigo'; ?></title>
```

---

Se isso não resolver o problema, verifique se o ficheiro termina com a extensão `.php` e o servidor tem suporte para `PHP`.

---

Se, depois de isso tudo, o problema permanecer, me informe sff.

Comment: @rbz , se o desenvolvedor quiser adicionar mais código a seguir a este código, precisa de usar `;`, porque o código é compilado todo junto!

Comment: Mas você não pode ir por dedução, e ainda dizer que é um erro. O exemplo na pergunta está clara. Ninguém se perguntou o porque do restante do código? E já está se preocupando com código que nem existe!?

Comment: @rbz, se chama precaução, e é uma boa prática adicionar `;` no final, vou corrigir a parte do "erro", obrigado.